# php - header location redirect: https to https, http to http

Tags: http, https, header, location

How do I properly use header function, so

```
header("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc"); //for http
```

and

```
header("location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc"); //for https
```

could be written in 1 string if possible?

.htaccess file will take care of all http pages to be redirected to https with no problem, but I believe it makes sense to use a proper syntax for http/https pages in `header("location:...)`, so it is correct for all browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$protocol='http';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
  if (strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTPS'])=='ON')
    $protocol='https';

header("location: $protocol://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc");
```

Answer (score 10):

You could also use the following code:

```
header("Location: //www.google.com");
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It appends the URL to the current root url.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != '') {
    header("location: https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc");
} else {
    header("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc")
}
```

This should work for Apache, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate the protocol-type by doing something like this:

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and 'https' or 'http'
```

Then

```
header("location: $protocol://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?para=abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the protocol by following code:

```
$protocol = strtolower( substr( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ], 0, 5 ) ) == 'https' ? 'https' : 'http';
```

and then redirect like this

```
header( 'location: ' . $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . '/?para=abc' );
```