# PHP header location to https

Tags: php, https, http-status-code-400

In my web app you get redirected after successful login via `header('Location: https://domain.com/loggedin')` but when its finished redirecting I get to following URL `http://domain.com:443/loggedin` which give (of course) following error

```
400 Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

What do I have to change? What did I do wrong or what do I have to add?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801340/php-header-location-redirect-https-to-https-http-to-http

Comment: See this http://security.stackexchange.com/q/46015/35190 as well

Comment: @Farkie I have looked at that thread already

Comment: @RahilWazir exactly that knowledge is wondering me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds absurd but after some thinking:
I added a slash (`/`) at the end so now it looks like this `header('Location: '.PROJECT_HTTP_ROOT.'/');`.

Works like it should now!

Comment: @nils No, why would you like to know that?